# How do I integrate a database into asp.net project using Postgresql and Petapoco?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, visual-studio, petapoco

I am not very good at setting up a project at all.  I am working on an application in VS that uses ASP.NET with MVC framework.  I am wanting to use a Postgresql database and use it in my project with Petapoco.  I have tried everything, and I added a connection string, but I can't get this to work..

Comment: Nobody will be able to help you, without reproducible code and or code segment in question, ie your connection string and how you use the value.

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="EMRConnectionString" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1:5432;Database=EMR;User Id=postgres; Password=postgres;" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

This is a portion of my app config file

Comment: When I run the Petapoco script, it says "Failed to load provider `Npgsql` - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."  But it is installed.

Comment: I've honestly never set up a project myself (where I work, they have always set the project up for me), so I want to get to a point where I'm understanding this.  We use SQL Server, so I'm trying to use Postgresql because it's free.  And I'm used to Petapoco so I would like to use that oo.

Comment: What version of Model View Controller?  What exactly do you not understand? I would be happy to help, or provide a sample project but we need more complete answers.

Comment: I checked my version, and it is 5.2.3.0.  I guess I don't know how to set up a project with a Postgresql database and Petapoco.  A sample project would be great.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/afppostgresqlintro.aspx

Comment: Alright, I will check this out tonight and let you know how it goes.  Thank you!

Comment: My connection string is correct, but I cannot get PetaPoco to work.  It gives the message, "Failed to load provider `Npgsql` - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."

Comment: https://www.npgsql.org You install that?

Comment: I had already installed it through Nuget, so I uninstalled and reinstalled.  I am trying to install it to the GAC (I have literally never done this and have no clue what I'm doing).  It gives me a link for a Windows installer, but I don't know what I'm supposed to do.  Here is the link for the installer: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases

Comment: I GOT IT!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE HELP!!!!

Comment: Glad it got sorted.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with Petapocoo 5.1.228

If you added it with nuget, you have a section within Project->Models->Generated.
in this section you'll have .tt and .ttinclude files

One is called Database.tt, once run will create objects with basic decoration needed, or what you have setuped. In this one, you have near the top a section called Settings with `ConnectionStringName` parameter. This one  has a comment that says "`// Uses last connection string in config if not specified`". This means if you don't set up a ConnectionStringName  in `web.config` file, it will take the lase one. So to configure it,

```
ConnectionStringName = "NorthwindConnection";  //this is my example using Northwind
```

then in web.config :

```
<add name="NorthwindConnection" connectionString="data source=.;Initial 
Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then if you have any trouble with DataProviders... go and read the doc in PetaPoco.Core.ttinclude this include how to add and check for DataProvider in GAC. And if you have the right set of driver installed.

Another word about Database.tt, there is settings you can use to tweak the generated POCOs in what namespaces, do I want the full database or exclude what... check it out! :P

Back in business, once you setted up database.tt right, right click and Run custom tool will do the job. On success, you'll have a Database.cs under the same path as database.tt. on error you have the same result with an exception to look up to.

The generated file will contains all POCOs and namesapaces you need to start using Petapoco....

in my case,

```
using NorthwindConnection;
```

in addithion with

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    var db = new PetaPoco.Database("NorthwindConnection");
    return db.Query<Customer>("SELECT * FROM Customers");
}
```

allows me to retrieve all customers.

EDIT: Data provider or connection trouble with driver: check PetaPoco.Core.ttinclude :

```
In order to work, the appropriate driver must be registered in the system machine.config file.  If you're
 using Visual Studio 2010 the file you want is here:

    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

 After making changes to machine.config you will also need to restart Visual Studio.

 Here's a typical set of entries that might help if you're stuck:

    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <add name="Odbc Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.Odbc" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc" type="System.Data.Odbc.OdbcFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <add name="OleDb Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OleDb" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for OleDb" type="System.Data.OleDb.OleDbFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <add name="OracleClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.OracleClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" type="System.Data.OracleClient.OracleClientFactory, System.Data.OracleClient, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.3.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/><add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
            <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Postgresql Server" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=2.0.11.91, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>

 Also, the providers and their dependencies need to be installed to GAC.  

 Eg; this is how I installed the drivers for PostgreSQL

     gacutil /i Npgsql.dll
     gacutil /i Mono.Security.dll
```

Hope this helps solving your issue.

Comment: My connection string is correct, and I am just still having trouble... whenever I run custom tool on Database.tt, it is still giving an error message saying that, "Failed to load provider `Npgsql` - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed."  It is installed...

Comment: Have you checked for GAC cache not beeing updated? ( gacutil /i Npgsql.dll)  Or checked in your system machine.config file ? If you're using Visual Studio 2010 the file you want is here: (default) C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config. Note: if you make any changes to machine.config you will also need to restart Visual Studio.